# Utility to get binary representation from string?

Tags: conversion, string

Is there a simple utility like `printf` that'll give me a "binary representation", i.e. a string like "01010010", from an input string? It would need to support multi-byte encodings.

Comment: i was going to say od, but it doesnt output binary. googling about using od for binary output, found this, might be helpful: http://blog.2of1.org/2011/03/24/binary-output-using-od-cut-and-perl/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`xxd -b`

([source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/display-binary-not-hex-or-od-actual-ones-and-zeros-700063/))

Comment: Nice, thank you! My Google didn't find it… :o)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this (and many other things) using [`figlet`](http://www.figlet.org/) with the [`binary`](http://www.figlet.org/fontdb.cgi) font.

```
$ echo foo | figlet -f binary
01100110 01101111 01101111
```

Comment: *@bahamat:* I love the style of `figlets` big font output (+1 for that :) , but I there is not 'binary' format for version 2.2.2..

Comment: I'm using 2.2.4, and I have the binary font. You have to download it from figlet.org (I already posted the link).

Comment: I downloaded `binary.flf`, and it works to just add a new *.flf* file to */usr/share/figlet*... Now that I've actually tried it, I'll mention that unless you manually modify `binary.flf`, it **does not** convert spaces to binary...